# How do I send an Object containing another object to the server?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, requestfactory

I am developing an application to collect questions (class name `Question`) and answers.

On my client there is a set of RadioButtons that can used to choose the subject of the question. The subjects (class name `Subject`) are stored in the database.

For storing in the database I use hibernate.

So my Question class has a property subject that is of the type `Subject`

When saving a question I obtain the database ID. How can I now store the proper subject to the database?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is this the problem you are facing? : 

**1.** You use the same class (Question and Subject) on the browser side (GWT compiled them into javascript) and also on the server-side the same classes have Hibernate annotations (or hibernate xml files) 

**2.** You also want to, REFER to the corresponding Subject when saving the Question in the DB 

**3.** The browser populates a new Subject object based on Radio Button selection and so new Subject records are created by hibernate instead of referring to the old ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my comment IS the problem you are facing,

For your case, You should have 2 separate versions of your subject and question.

One set is a DTO (Data transfer object), while other set is the persistent set of classes.
The DTO classes **SubjectDTO** and **QuestionDTO** classes are GWT compiled and are sent to and from the browser with service calls. The **QuestionDTO** contains the entered Question and selected subject name from the radio buttons as primitive strings. When the user clicks to save the question you make a service call and send the **QuestionDTO** to the server. The server then does a findByName of subject on the DB, fetches the actual pre-existing **SubjectPersistent** record from the DB and puts it in a new **QuestionPersistent** along with the actual string representing the question the user entered and saves it. Thus you have referred to an existing subject - an actual foreign key is created to the subject while saving the question.

Choose whatever naming scheme you want to for the DTOs and Persistant classes (I named them Models and Domains) but they will have to be separate eventually, as your application grows more complex.